# ICQ Messenger - Recovery Of Historical Chats

Tags: windows-xp, data-recovery, pidgin, icq

I have uninstalled an older version of ICQ. I triple checked that I did NOT, in the uninstall process, set it to delete the historical conversations (and anything else related to ICQ history). Then I downloaded and installed latest version of ICQ.

All my past logs of history conversations are gone. I checked 10 times through the entire Documents and Settings folder (yes entire one), also clicked every single contact with right mouse button, chose ''History'' option. Everything is gone and there were some extremely important details in the saved conversations within older version of ICQ.

I tried R-Undelete, Glary Utilities, Restoration, Avira Unerase, Recuva recovery softwares and nothing works. I must get my logs of history chats back. Please help.

Same question for PIDGIN messenger.

Comment: What 5 different recovery softwares have you tried? please add this to the question

Comment: done. Hopefully someone could please help. I need the data urgently :-(

Comment: See my answer :) hopefully that works for you. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try using [system restore](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_system_restore_hss_access.mspx?mfr=true) to roll back your computer to before you updated ICQ.

Keep in mind this will restore all data to the date that you select including any instant messaging you have done since.

The link above tells you how to access system restore. [This link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/system-restore-xp.htm) gives you step-by-step instructions.

Comment: MalwareManiac I have 3 questions about your answer. First is if you could please tell me how can I restore it back then to the current time? I have been doing many work and need it to be restored back to the current time after saving logs to the cd/usb key. Second is: are you sure this will restore ICQ history chats logs? I am asking because I already uninstalled older version on purpose to install latest one. Third is there any way to then test/check that restore back to the current time was successful? Any good method to check this? I know I could just update icq it but its too late :-(

Comment: MalwareManiac hello?

Comment: @MyName unfortunately you cant restore it back to current time after you run the system restore. Your best bet would be to make an image of your drive using [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) and save to an external drive or some other storage device, then you can restore your computer using system restore, save whatever you need off to a usb drive, then restore the image back to the hard drive

Comment: does that make sense? (sorry about the delay)

Comment: Is restoring then available on some virtual computer where I could simply deleted the restored file (virtual hard drive from the past)? not sure if you know what i mean.. something like restoring on virtual place but without effecting ''real'' hard drive. I don't have experiences with vmware or similar applications. Is this what you meant with Macrium Reflect software?

Comment: Or (sorry for second message in a row - please read previous too) if I create image file and then use it on either some different pc or preferable virtual machine (i think there is some website called ''alwaysonpc.com'' or something like that) and use it (image file) there. Then there I can pickup needed text of conversations and thats it. Would this be possible with your Macrium Reflect suggestion?

Comment: and therefore i would acutally do the system restore on image file. Otherwise I would need another option. Cannot restored all the data on real hard drive.

Comment: @MyName I dont have that much experience with virtual machines either.

Comment: @MyName heres what I would do: 1.make an image and save it preferably to an external hard drive with Macrium Reflect(virtual machine would work too) 2. restore the computer with system restore 3. Copy all your logs onto flash drive 4. restore the image to your drive using the same macrium reflect software(you will have to reinstall it) 5. copy your logs into the machine.

Comment: Im not exactly sure how it would work with any vm software. Im the wrong person to ask about that